I want to link my subcategory to related category in forms.py. How to do that?
I'm currently working on a Python project where I'm trying to get category from its own related subcategories. However, I'm encountering an issue where the subcategory field, it doesn't show anything. There are 4 files that I'm uploading:
This is models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True,null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
    
class Subcategory(models.Model):
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory_name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)

This is forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Ad,Photo,Subcategory,Category

class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email is already taken.")
        return email
      
class AdForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), empty_label=None)
    subcategory = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subcategory.objects.none())


class Meta:
        model = Ad
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'category', 'subcategory', 'price', 'location']

This is my views.py
def publish_ad(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AdForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')  # Redirect to a success page or any other URL
    else:
        form = AdForm()
    return render(request, 'market/publish_ad.html', {'form': form})

This is a html file
{% extends "market/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
<!-- publish_ad.html -->
{% block content %}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Publish Ad</button>
</form>

{% endblock content %}

For example I would expect to get
Car(category)->Electric(subcategory), Trucks(subcategory)
